# Statistical test for significant different between two temperature depth profile

Tags: statistical-significance

I have two sea water temperature column from two different location and I want to test if they are significantly different.
KS test and MANOVA test classify the water depth profile into different layers, which I don't want.
on the other hand, kernel density estimate take the whole profile at once.
What other statistics test could be used?

Comment: Can you say why you don;'t want to pair according to corresponding layers at the two locations? Does it make sense to pair according depth measurements (ignoring layers)?

Comment: because I working on fish catch modeling each catch has a specific depth. The problem is that the fishing vessel don't record the oceanographic temperature. The only way to obtains these is through argo data. But before  if I don't have the exact oceanographic variables reading can I take for a nearby location, that why I want to test before starting the modeling.

Answer (score 1):

You have one profile from location A, and one profile from location B.

Each profile (please correct me if I am mistaken) comprises a serie of correlated temperatures, i.e. two temperatures close in the profile will be more similar than two more distant temperatures.

The bad news is that you have only one profile per location.

Each profile is considered as one individual, with the many increasingly deep measurements being correlated measures of the same serie. That's similar to measuring, for example, the height of someone from age 1 to 50. Or the concentration of free cadmium in soil from 0 to 100cm deep. You could perform a million measurements along the profile, it stays one profile.

So you can say that the two profiles you wish to compare are different, visually different.

However you can't test if these two profiles are significantly different. It is the same as asking : are these two guys significantly different based on their height ? They are different. Because these are two different people. The same conclusion holds for the two profiles of temperatures.

To test whether the two ***locations*** are significantly different by their profile of temperature, you need multiple independent profiles at each location.